# How to generate Fibonacci series in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Currently I am working on a task, where I should prompt the user to input a number from the console (e.g. 1) and then:

- First two elements of ArrayList are the input number(1);
- Every next element at the ArrayList is equal to sum of previous two;
- Print the ArrayList.

Here is my trainee code:) :

```
public class ex3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number :");
    int number = sc.nextInt();

    List<Integer>numbersList = new ArrayList<>();
    numbersList.add(number);
    numbersList.add(number);

    int k = 0,a = number,b = number;
    for(k=0;k<=10;k++) {
        k = a + b;
        System.out.println(k + " ");
        a=b;
        b=k;
    }
  }
}
```

I see that obviously I have not put the fibonacci series into the ArrayList.

Comment: Seems like we would be doing your homework then :)

Comment: hah.. no i was trying couple of approaches and..at the end i asked here:)

Comment: Remember to include your different approaches, you might be onto something :)

Comment: that's true..thanks!

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking (unless you just want us to finish writing your code). It seems like you might be asking how to add an element to an ArrayList, but you already do that elsewhere in your code. So... just repeat?

Comment: You're not putting very much at all into the arrayList, except from the two initial values. You neither read from, nor do you write to the numbersList. How long should the process run? 10 steps? Pass your numbersList to a method, and then work with that method only. No k, a, b.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for(int i=2;i<range;i++){
numberslist.add(numberslist.get(i-1)+numberslist.get(i-2))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution below:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class ex3{
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter a number :");
      int n = sc.nextInt();

      List<Integer> numbersList = new ArrayList<>();
      int first = 0, second = 1, fib;
      numbersList.add(first);
      numbersList.add(second);
      
      for(int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
          fib = second + first;
          first = second;
          second = fib;
          numbersList.add(fib);
      }
      System.out.println(numbersList);
  }
}
```